# Не работает клик по элементу

Tags: javascript, test-automation, puppeteer

Есть код:

```
const checkbox = await this.page.$('input[type=checkbox]');
await checkbox.click();
```

Получаю ошибку:  Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement (((
Элемент в момент клика точно присутствует на странице и виден.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и [mcve] для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. С двумя этими строчками кода - не воспроизводится.

Comment: Элемент может и присутствует, но возможно при загрузке js его еще нет в DOM. Почитайте про делегирование в JS, это то что вам нужно в этой ситуации

Comment: @Alexandr, Не факт, что делегирование окажется наиболее удобным решением - возможно что ожидание `DOMContentLoaded` или мутации элемента будет уместнее. Подождем улучшающей правки вопроса автором.

Comment: Интересненько `await`  вы используете. (Если что - это сарказм)

Comment: В документации к puppeteer был такой пример:
```const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  const hrefElement = await page.$('a');
  await hrefElement.click(); ```